# How do you bring a visible NativeWindow to the front of all applications in a Adobe AIR App

Tags: adobe, air

The application I'm working on is a HTML AIR application based on the AIR 2.5 SDK.

The application starts two windows: the first is a hidden window that registers it's self on the system tray (it's windows specific); the second is a visible lightweight window displaying showing various bits of information. Since the visible window is lightweight, there is no task bar entry to always the user bring the window to the front if hidden under other application windows.

The requirement is that on clicking the system tray icon the display window will be brought to the front.

My current solution looks something like:

```
function handleClick(){
    var nativeDisplayWindow = findDisplayWindow(); 
    nativeDisplayWindow.alwaysInFront = true;
    nativeDisplayWindow.alwaysInFront = false;
}
function findDisplayWindow(){
    // looks in air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows for the 
    // the display window and returns it
}
```

It works but really doesn't feel right.

I've tried using `NativeWindow.orderToFront()` & `NativeWindow.activate()` and various combinations of all the other method.

Is this the correct way to bring a window to the front of all application windows in AIR?

Comment: I had the same issue and this was the only solution that worked. IMHO it's logical enough to be acceptable without having a panic attack over semantics. AKA I like this solution just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

If you try casting your `nativeDisplayWindow` as a Window you should then be able to do something like:

```
function handleClick(){
   var nativeDisplayWindow:Window = findDisplayWindow() as Window; 
   nativeDisplayWindow.orderToFront();
}
```

I don't know if this is what you are looking for or whether I've just repeated what you've explained?

Comment: I'm afraid trying orderToFront()... it just doesn't seem to cut the mustard

Comment: what kind of thing are you looking for? Have you tried restoring the window? This may bring it into focus?

Comment: NativeWindow.orderToFront() brings the window the top that application's windows, I had to force the window to the top of *all* windows (on Windows in particular). The exact use case was a chromeless window with a system tray window, on clicking the system tray had to bring the window to the fore. The actual app is now available (including my hack) http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/weather/uk/desktopwidget.html

Comment: The link is 404. It would be useful for the hack to be documented as an answer to the question. Classic case of ... http://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: It doesn't bring it front of the modal window. :(